# Show fixed width columns with fluid columns - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have fluid pages that works perfectly fine, but sometimes a page can have ads on the sides that are fixed width 140px.

Please see picture below:

[image]

The ads are added dynamically so at any time the page will or will not have ads.

I must have a div for them always, and the page must adapt if there are ads or not. And sometimes it can have just one ad not both.

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="width:140px; float:left">Fixed Width</div>     
  <div class="col-lg-6>Fluid Width</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6>Fluid Width</div>
  <div style="width:140px; float:right;">Fixed Width</div> 
</div>
```

So, the cases are:

- no ads
- 1 ad
- 2 ads

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you show the code in a fiddler? It will help in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a flexbox solution for this, one of the many things the [`flexbox module`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can do to your layout. *Explanation in code comments*

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/90xmLaja/)

**CSS**

```
/* The Essential flexbox rules */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
.ad {
  flex: 0 1 140px; /* Flex-grow: 0, Don't grow on resize and fixed width of 140px */
}
.center-content {
  flex: 1; /* Grow when the ads are removed */
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="ad">Ad Content</div>
  <div class="center-content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="ad">Ad Content</div>
</div>
```

**Modified Output:**

```js
$('.btn-primary.first').on('click', function() {
  $('.ad').first().toggleClass('remove');
});

$('.btn-primary.second').on('click', function() {
  $('.ad').last().toggleClass('remove');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: roboto;
}
.ad {
  background: #3A97D4;
  flex: 0 1 0;
  flex-basis: 140px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.center-content {
  margin: 0 2%;
  flex: 1;
  background: #838383;
  padding: 10px;
}
.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="ad">Ad Content</div>
  <div class="center-content">
    Content
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary first">Toggle 1st ad</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary second">Toggle 2nd ad</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ad">Ad Content</div>
</div>
```